# how can i downgrade a library in android studio from api 23 to api 19

Tags: android

I am developing an application for Android API level 19, but I upgraded libraries for api level 23 and when I compile the project I have these errors.

Image error : [Error Build App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN4EU.png)

Image sdk manager : [SDK manager extras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpH49.png)

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource 

found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Theme.Material.Light\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Button\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Large\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Small\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Button\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorAccent\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":119,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10379,"endColumn":39,"endOffset":10398}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorButtonNormal\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":123,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10697,"endColumn":45,"endOffset":10722}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlActivated\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":121,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10525,"endColumn":49,"endOffset":10554}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlHighlight\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":122,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10611,"endColumn":49,"endOffset":10640}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlNormal\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":120,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10445,"endColumn":46,"endOffset":10471}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorPrimary\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":117,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10235,"endColumn":40,"endOffset":10255}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorPrimaryDark\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":118,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10303,"endColumn":44,"endOffset":10327}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:windowElevation\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":126,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10880,"endColumn":43,"endOffset":10903}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorAccent\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":119,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10379,"endColumn":39,"endOffset":10398}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorButtonNormal\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":123,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10697,"endColumn":45,"endOffset":10722}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlActivated\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":121,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10525,"endColumn":49,"endOffset":10554}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlHighlight\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":122,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10611,"endColumn":49,"endOffset":10640}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorControlNormal\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":120,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10445,"endColumn":46,"endOffset":10471}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorPrimary\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":117,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10235,"endColumn":40,"endOffset":10255}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:colorPrimaryDark\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":118,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10303,"endColumn":44,"endOffset":10327}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027android:windowElevation\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":126,"startColumn":20,"startOffset":10880,"endColumn":43,"endOffset":10903}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ActionButton\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Small\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\jvera\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Bathand19\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\22.2.0\\res\\values-v21\\values-v21.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\REPO\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


Gradle
BUILD FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\REPO\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Gradle config

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jvera.bathand19"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer : [downgrade library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183122#makechanges)

"You need to delete the build tools 23 from the sdk manager and then in the sdk folder (yes the actual folder) open up sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7
blow away the entire 23.0.0 folder 
then in the same appcompat folder open maven-metadata.xml and delete the one line 23.0.0

clean and rebuild"

This method too work for play-services library (play-services:7.0.0 for api level 19)

Edit the file **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

change

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

clean and rebuild.